# How to save pickle file has an object or variable and reuse it in python

Tags: python, variables, pickle

How to save pickle file has an object or variable and reuse it in python !?

I need to save the space where my python programing will create multiple pickle file and save it in hard disk by this way space is consuming very fast I need to save the space for that. I am thinking to save the pickle file has object or variable and reuse it when it needed in python

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
import pickle

# Object or variable to be saved
my_object = {'name': 'John', 'age': 30}

# Save the object as a pickle file
with open('my_object.pkl', 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(my_object, file)
```

Above you are saving the dict has a pkl file.

```
import pickle

# Load the object from the pickle file
with open('my_object.pkl', 'rb') as file:
    loaded_object = pickle.load(file)

# Access the loaded object
print(loaded_object)
```

with this you are loading the pickle file in a variable